# Why is my sugar paste becoming a brick?

Tags: carbohydrates, food-chemistry

I know this question may sound to be not inherent with chemistry, but since making the sugar wax paste involves acids and heating, I thought this would be the right place.

Preparing the paste is quite simple:
1 cup of sugar, 2 tbs of lemon juice and 2 tbs of water. Then the process expects to heat the compound until it becomes abra colored. The the mixture is moved away to cool down.The result would be a malleable and sticky paste at ambient temperature. My problem is that my paste becomes really hard and impossible to shape.

What could I do to avoid the compound to become a brick?

Comment: It may be more appropriate for Seasoned Advice (Cooking SE)

Comment: My main concern is how can I avoid sugar to crystalize?

Comment: Are you making caramel candy or something else? If yes, this receipe sounds *really* weird (the sugar should be caramelized before adding fluid, then you probably add way more fluid).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have enough liquid in the recipe. Double the lemon and water to 4 tablespoons each, and you should have better luck. Adding more liquid will bring the sugar/liquid ratio more in line with what is needed to make the paste pliable. Add more liquid if you still have issues.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVKrLumCEpA) you seem to be using (much) less water and lemon juice than you should. To your solace, a bit of google-ing shows that a lot of people tried to prepare sugar wax without obtaining the expected results.